# Can I have a replacement bank card shipped to a mailbox in Melbourne, Australia?

Tags: australia, payment-cards, security, mail, shipping

Today I discovered that my bank card was cloned and $2500 was stolen from my account yesterday.

I called my bank and they said they can only ship my card to my home address in Melbourne (which makes sense). I plan to get to Melbourne by the time the new card will arrive (April 23) but I am not staying in a hotel nor a house – most likely a hostel.

Is there any way I can ship it to a fixed mailbox so I can be sure the card does not get lost on the way? How can I ensure that my card arrives in Australia, and I won't have to reorder another one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your home country and bank?
No, no details needed, this is not a scam attempt :-).
Knowing may help answers.

I'd expect the following to be the best solution if the service is available:

- In the past and almost certainly still you can send items to a Post Office to be held pending your collection. You would definitely want to check with Australia Post to see if this service is available and, if so, what mailing and physical office addresses are available for this service. As the letter would still be in the mailing system until collected the security would be good.

Alternatively, if you know anyone in Australia they could act as a relay. My daughter is a hospital doctor in Canberra. She may be happy to act as a mail relay point. I imagine that you can get same day courier services from Canberra to Melbourne and pick up at a courier office.  Obviously you'd need some more details before you trusted you card to that arrangement :-). If all else fails contact me offlist and we can discuss. My email address is on my profile page if required. (I'm in NZ).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! My home country is Argentina and the bank issuing the card is Chase Bank from USA. I will try to check with the post office to see if they have that service available. That would be good. I need to make sure which is the right post office though.